# Combobox_Change function for combobox's created with .Controls.add function*

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls, combobox, userform

Let me start by saying that I have searched far and wide for hours before answering this question.

Situation (all working) -

User is to specify the number of apples in a basket

Example - user specifies 2 apples. This creates two pages within a multipage with comboboxes and textbox's.

The combobox's are populated with a database of apple names. The user chooses one.

Desired:

When a user chooses an apple from the combobox I would like the textbox's on that multipage to populate with the apples characteristics. In other words I need my code to fire any time a user selects an apple from this combobox. This is not a combobox created from the toolbar, so I cant seem to use "private sub Combobox_Change".

Below is the code that I use to create the combobox:

```
Set ComboBoxL = MultiPage1.Pages(pgCount).Controls.Add("Forms.combobox.1", _
"ComboBoxL" & pgCount)

With ComboBoxL

.Top = 1 * FromTop
.Left = LeftDist
.List = Sheets("TestLightList").Range("A1:A100").Value
```

This is the code that I use to pull the value into the textbox, it works in testing (just running it in another part of the code) but doesnt work when needed because I dont know how to tell VBA to fire it off when the user selects an item from the combobox above

```
userform2!textboxC1.Value = Application.index(Range("'TestLightList'!$A$2:$E$500"), _
Application.Match(userform2!ComboBoxL1.Value, Range( _
"'TestLightList'!$A$2:$A$500"), 0), 2)
```

- Note that in this snippit of code im working off of the first combobox. The formula creates a series of them in numerical order.

Thank you!

Comment: would be much easier to help you if you show us part of your code... do you want to fire action based on new selection in UserForm.TextBox or UserForm.ComboBox?

Comment: Thank you for the response KazJaw I added them to the original post.

Comment: after you have edited your question is perfectly understood :), +1 for you for that. Anyway, there is possibility to add VBA code using other VBA instruction. However, there are some safety issues which require to tick one additional option is Excel app safety window. If this code is only for you I'll suggest exploring this way. If you will share your project with others this will rather not work.

Comment: Thanks :) Some sleep alleviated the frustrations. Unfortunately it will be used by a few people.

Comment: So, as you've written, user can take 2 apples which result with 2 pages. Is the number of apples to-be-chosen limited or unlimited?

Comment: Limited to 10. Each page has one combobox for AppleType. The associated textboxes are designated for Apple Characteristics. When a user selects an apple type I want the default characteristics to populate, however the user can manually override any of it.

Comment: what about this idea- you would create all 10 pages but instead of adding/removing you will hide/show them. It that situation you could have all your events in place.

Comment: Unfortunately, each project will have a variable number of Apples. I debated this for awhile and managed to build a lot of code this way being that I feel its the proper way to go about it given the needs. If it's impossible then I may need to rethink my strategy.

Comment: Kaz, what setting would enable this? I will probably try to promote this question or re-raise it, but in the interim maybe your suggestion will help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question...

Comment: No problem. From earlier in our conversation - "However, there are some safety issues which require to tick one additional option is Excel app safety window."